# sort_by a value that isn't always present – ActiveRecord | Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm working on a listing site that works with `Location` and `Review` models. I was to be able to order the list of locations by their average rating calculated by any reviews that exist for the location.

```rb
Location.all.sort_by(&:rating)
```

throws the error:

```
An ArgumentError occurred in search#search:

  comparison of BigDecimal with nil failed
```

Notice `rating` is a model method, not a field in the database, hence the use of `sort_by`.
How should I best modify to get this going?
Any help would be much appreciated!

```rb
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews

  def rating
    self.reviews.average('rating')
  end
end
```

```rb
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :rating, presence: true
  validates :comment, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :location, presence: true
end
```

Comment: `average` returns `nil` if there are no `reviews`. To fix it, you could exclude locations without reviews, sort them separately, or provide a default rating.

Comment: Ouch that is going to hurt from a performance standpoint, since you have to load the reviews for each `location` one at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having to overwrite your `rating` method (you might want it to return `nil` if there are no reviews), you can use the following:

```
Location.all.sort_by { |l| l.rating || 0 }
```

This will allow any location without a rating to fallback to a default of `0` in the ordering *only* if it's not got a rating.

Then, for instance, you could still distinguish between locations with a genuine review score of `0` and those without any reviews.

If you're concerned about genuine scores of `0` clashing with those with not reviews, you can set the default lower, i.e. `-1`.

For example, you might have somewhere you want to display review scores as follows:

```
= @location.rating || "Location has no reviews"
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you can return 0 if no review are available:

```
  def rating
    return 0 unless reviews.any?
    reviews.average(:rating)
  end
```